# Invalid read of size 1 when printing a string from a linked list of structs

Tags: c, valgrind

I have created a singly-linked list of structs and I am trying to print a string from them. My linked lists are defined as:

```
typedef struct LinkedListNode
{
    void* data;
    struct LinkedListNode* next;
} LinkedListNode;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    int count;
    struct LinkedListNode* head;
} LinkedList;
```

My struct is defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
    char missile[10]; /* trying to print this */
    funcPtr missileFunc;
} missileStruct;
```

And my printf statement is this:

```
printf("Print this: %s\n",(*(missileStruct*)((*currentNode).data)).missile);
```

Valgrind outputs:

```
==11680== Invalid read of size 1
==11680==    at 0x4E88CC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==11680==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==11680==    by 0x401F9E: game (game.c:53)
==11680==    by 0x401112: menu (menu.c:57)
==11680==    by 0x400A6F: main (main.c:13)
==11680==  Address 0xa656c676e6973 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==11680== 
==11680== 
==11680== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==11680==  General Protection Fault
==11680==    at 0x4E88CC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==11680==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==11680==    by 0x401F9E: game (game.c:53)
==11680==    by 0x401112: menu (menu.c:57)
==11680==    by 0x400A6F: main (main.c:13)
Print this: ==11680==
```

Comment: You will need to show more code and more information from `valgrind`.  About all we can say so far is ”you are mismanaging memory somehow”.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok, I have edited my post to show more from valgrind

Comment: That's a start.  Now, where's the code that caused that trace.  You need to do quite a lot of minimization work to create an [MCVE].  You have at least three source files and at least one header.  It needs to be reduced small enough to fit in the question. And the minimized code must reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not sure if I'll be able to do that because the creation of the linked list requires 3 different c files and I can't figure out a way to minimise the code. Also, the weird thing is that printf statement doesn't work in my actual program works perfectly when I ran it in a test file without changing anything.

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to help you much without your code.  If it's any help, you probably have a pointer that's been overwritten by text.  The 'address', treated as an array of bytes, has a null byte, a newline, and the characters "elgnis", assuming big-endian ordering.  With little-endian ordering, that's "single", newline, null byte.  So, you probably are mismanaging memory during input as you type `single` as the input.

Comment: You should probably replace `(*(missileStruct*)((*currentNode).data)).missile` with `((missileStruct *)currentNode->data)->missile`, and note that `void` pointers make the cast unavoidable (no pun intended).  The `->` notation was created to avoid having a plethora of brackets and stars, though the `void *` makes the cast and its `*` and parentheses inevitable — unless you create local variable `missileStruct *mp = currentNode->data;` and print `mp->missile` instead — no casts, stars or parentheses needed except for the `*` in the pointer variable definition.

Comment: are you sure you have assigned missileStruct with initialized missile address to currentNode.data?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Turns out I had a typo in my typedef struct in one of my h files where I wrote char* missile instead of char missile[10].